# MongoError: cannot establish topology capabilities as driver is still in process of connecting at Server.capabilities

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to mongoDB via mongoose.connect and I continue to get the error:

```
/Users/Documents/Business/01000100/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:133
          throw err;
                ^
MongoError: cannot establish topology capabilities as driver is still in process of connecting
    at Server.capabilities
```

auth_server.js:

```
    var express         = require('express')
var body_parser     = require('body-parser')
var cookie_parser   = require('cookie-parser')
var express_session = require('express-session')
var mongo_store     = require('connect-mongo')({session:express_session})
var mongoose        = require('mongoose')
var morgan          = require('morgan')
var port            = 8080

//MODELS
require('./models/user_model.js')

//CONFIG
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db')

var app = express()

//VIEW ENGINE
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express)
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'html')

//MIDDLEWARE
app.use(morgan('dev'))//logging requests
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookie_parser())
app.use(express_session({
    secret: '2!H$,Br2&1XW74zpd897ytf lbph=-0987654edfvbn5Q4AQ0]k7XX2Plh915ZV2)0)2DvHK}4KA"^6J!TY;x4z04',
    cookie: {maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000},
    store: new mongo_store({
        db: mongoose.connection.db,
        collection: 'sessions'
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

//ROUTES
require('./routes')(app)

//START
app.listen(port)
console.log('Santa is listening on ' + port)
```

Does anyone know what is causing this problem or how to fix it? I've spent a bunch of hours on it researching and I still cannot seem to pinpoint a solution. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something, and what is likely the session store information, which does not use the mongoose methods directly is trying to access the database before the connection has been established. The mongoose methods themselves hide this away and "queue" the operations until after the connection is actually made.

Wrap all your application startup in the "connection" event to make sure an connection has been established:

```
//CONFIG
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');   // Does not wait for connection here

var app = express();

mongoose.connection.on("connect",function(err) {   // But this waits for connection

    // All Setup here - But especially this

    app.use(express_session({
        secret: '2!H$,Br2&1XW74zpd897ytf lbph=-0987654edfvbn5Q4AQ0]k7XX2Plh915ZV2)0)2DvHK}4KA"^6J!TY;x4z04',
        cookie: {maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000},
        store: new mongo_store({
            db: mongoose.connection.db,
            collection: 'sessions'
        }),
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }))


    //START
    app.listen(port)
    console.log('Santa is listening on ' + port)

})
```

Comment: WOW! thank you soooo much! for some stupid reason I thought that bit would be executed serially