# cant connect to Local mongodb server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

when trying to connect to mongo db from the project directory i get this

*/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:133
          throw err;
                ^
MongoError: cannot connect to server
    at Collection.listIndexes (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1712:11)
    at indexInformation (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1531:25)
    at Db.indexInformation (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1498:44)
    at ensureIndex (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1003:8)
    at Db.ensureIndex (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:982:44)
    at ensureIndex (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1772:13)
    at Collection.ensureIndex (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1760:44)
    at connectionReady (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:141:27)
    at Db.collection (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:425:20)
    at initWithNativeDb (/Users/tadeothompson/Documents/design work/stressful/site/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:207:20)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3*

managed to connect using a simple app (code below)

```
*

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
      }
    });
```

*

```
the main node file of the app in question code is below:


var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')({session: expressSession});
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/users_model.js');
var conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stressfullproject');
var app = express();
app.engine('html', require('ejs')._express); 
app.set('views', './site' + '/views');        
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'stress',
    cookie: {maxAge: 60*60*1000},
    store: new mongoStore({
        db: mongoose.connection.db,
        collection: 'sessions'
    })
}));
require('./routes/routes')(app);
app.listen(80);
```

*

my defined schema

```
 *var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: String,
    hashed_password: String
})
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)*
```

because i can connect with the other app, im thinking its an issue with one of my modules? ive searched all over.

thanks in advance

Comment: could you give the full stack trace please.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that you are using two modules namely MongoClient and mongoose both are trying to connect to port 27017. Now in this race only one will win and will lock that port. If you try and bind to that port it will give you an error, similar to the one you are getting above. My suggestion, don't use MongoClient. use only mongoose. There is a lot of help available for mongoose and many video tutorials on youtube use it. 
If that doesn't help let me know.

Let's prep you up with some code shall we. I don't use MongoClient now, but when I used to I wrote this code, see of it works. If it doesn't please paste the stacktrace.

```
var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient,

server=require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoclient=new MongoClient(new server('localhost',27017));

mongoclient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/course',function(err,db)
{
    if(err) throw err;
    //var db=mongoclient.db('course');
    var query={'grade':100};

    db.collection('grades').findOne(query,function(err,doc)
        {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.dir(doc);
            db.close();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; I am not running the two modules at the same time. This issue has been present long before I created the 'small test module'. I only created the test module and ran it separately in order to see if a connection would be made, hopefully ruling out an issue with mongod server.

Comment: so your mongod server is running fine? `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db` opens up a connection??

Comment: Make sure your port 27017 is freed up. by running `netstat -tulpn`

Comment: Better than no error right? now let's debug it and see what happens? Did you change the name of collection and DB? Make sure you get some result when you run the same query in mongo console. If that is there you should be getting results

Comment: mongod server is running fine. it waits for a connection and opens one when 'mongo' cmd is used in another terminal.

Comment: Cool. And when you run the command in shell do you get any results?

Comment: i didnt change the collection, or DB name. i left the code exactly how you typed it and ran it.

Comment: Dude, how will that work? You need your own collection and DB. No probs run it with your own DB i.e. `stressfullproject` and your own collection i.e `sessions` if I am not wrong, and let me know. I have the Stack Exchange app so I know exactly when  you comment. Come back and let me know.

Comment: i can use the shell to create the DB, and collection, insert, and query with returned results working

Comment: the same error occurs when trying to connect with the main node app mentioned above. im noticing though that, connect-mongo states support for mongoose 4.0 but not necessarily 4.2.4 which is what im using. this may be the issue

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer in another stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648043/mongoerror-cannot-establish-topology-capabilities-as-driver-is-still-in-process)

the problem was that the session (or something else outside of mongoose) was trying to connect to the database BEFORE mongoose established a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Either one of two issues - either you are calling an undefined schema (mongoose) or you have a function requiring next but next is undefined. I've run into this problem many times and it's documented lack of error handling with mongoose. You need to define some error handling early in your app.js file.

Comment: i have defined the schema in another module:   (code added above). ill have to get back to you on the 'next' issue

Answer (score 0):

**Mongodb version v4.2.6** ---
**Node.js version: v14.2.0**

first, make sure you are running mongodb local server, check for exsiting db by bellow command:

```
show dbs
```

output:
[image]

Now I want to connect with database **tours-test**

first install mongooes by command

```
npm i mongoose
```

Now in you connection.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conStr = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/tours-test';
mongoose
  .connect(conStr, {
    usedNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((con) => console.log('DB connection successful'));
// remember mongoose.connect() return Promise
```